# Kill Process if its frozen

Tags: powershell

I want to kill Chrome if its frozen; therefore I wrote a script for PowerShell and it was linked with a task scheduled in Task Manager that runs every hour. The problem is that it always kills Chrome not only when it's frozen.
What is wrong with the script?

```
$response = Get-Process -Name chrome |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Responding

if ($response -ne 'True') {
    taskkill /f/im chrome
} else {
    Write-Host "Its Good"
    exit
}
```

Comment: Why not use a straight pipe: `Get-Process -Name chrome | Where-Object Responding -ne $True | Stop-Process -Force`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell scripts have a `.ps1` extension, for one.  And you have an anti-pattern in your conditional:

```
$response -ne 'True'
```

`$response` is a boolean, so it either is or isn't.  You shouldn't compare it to a string.

I'd suggest something like this because chrome spawns *a lot* of processes:

```
foreach ($chrome in Get-Process -Name chrome) {
    if (-not $chrome.Responding) {
        $chrome | Stop-Process -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script :
The property responding is a boolean.
The variable $response is either an array containing boolean (if you have multiple Chrome processes running or a boolean (if you have just one Chrome process running)

When you write 
`if ($response -ne 'True')`
You say : "if the $response array is not equal to the string 'True'".
Edit: after testing thanks to @TheIncorrigible1, $response is casted as strings

To perform your request I would suggest the following :

```
$response = get-process -Name chrome


$response | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Responding) {
    #Your process is responding 'no problemo'
    Write-Host "$($_.ProcessName) is responding"
    }
    else {
    #Your process is not responding
    $_ | stop-process -force #edited after testing
    Write-Host "$($_.ProcessName) killed"
    }

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `if the $response array is not equal` this is wrong.  It acts as a *filter* against the array and will type-cast the booleans to strings.  Additionally, `taskkill $_` won't work.

Comment: Yes thank you for the feedback, edited the post to match your suggestion.